# C# sometimes the first command running after the second command

Tags: c#, .net, command

Sometimes when I set a PictureBox visible to false (for example) or set the text of some TextBox and then write "System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(X)" (for example) the first command carried out just after the sleep command.

How can it to be?
Are there some commands that work in the background?

it's make me confused.
It makes a lot of bugs in my projects.

Comment: post the relevant code

Comment: Are you using threading or backgroundworkers?

Comment: You make UI thread to sleep so it does not refresh the UI! When it wakes after `X` ms then it refreshes the UI and you see the changes.

Comment: @dotctor you are assuming that the other task isn't running on the UI thread. Thread.Sleep() should block the operation until the time has elapsed when on the same thread

Comment: @Alec - he's assuming it is, surely?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you might be waiting for events to fire. Try this:

```
pic.Visible = false;
Application.DoEvents();
sleep(1000);
```

See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.application.doevents%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: WOW! Perfect... Thank you very much! :D  Very much better... Fast answer!